# How to inherit Ink! traits/contracts

Tags: ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts

I am trying to inherit a trait in ink! as follows:

```rust
#[ink::trait_definition]
trait Erc20 {
    // ...
}

#[ink::trait_definition]
trait CustomErc20: Erc20 {
    // ...
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
ink! trait definitions with supertraits are not supported, yet
```

Is it possible to inherit contracts/traits in ink!, like in solidity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not inheritance, it is called [supertrait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#supertraits). It is a bound for the trait that if someone implements your `CustomErc20`, he also should implement the `Erc20` trait.

ink! right now doesn't support it(your error says to you about it). Maybe it will be fixed during [this](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/737) issue or [this](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/631).

You can use [`openbrush::trait_definition`](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts#default-implementation-in-ink-traits) macro that allows adding bounds. But you need to use it in combination with the `openbrush::contract` macro(instead of `ink::contract`).

Right now, OpenBrush allows adding any bounds(defined with `openbrush::trait_definition`, `ink::trait_definition` and common rust traits). But in the next release, OpenBursh will allow adding only bounds defined via `openbrush::trait_definition`. It is because traits defined with the `trait_definition` macro are public and should not use bounds related to a specific language or implementation.